# How does this CSS code center a webpage?

Tags: css

How does this CSS code center a webpage?

```
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color:#000;
    background:#fff;
}
#body {
    width:870px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#ddd;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
margin: auto;
```

centers any block.

But that's not the `body` that is centered, just a `div` whose id is "body" (which I find a little misleading).

Comment: It's important to note, though, that `margin: auto` translates to `margin-top: auto; margin-left: auto; margin-bottom: auto; margin-right: auto;`, but only the left and the right margins result in centering behavior. (That is, the div doesn't center vertically. `margin-top: auto` and `margin-bottom: auto` are effectively ignored.)

Answer (score 2):

Be careful when naming classes or IDs the same as body/head/footer/etc.  The code you posted will work fine, because the `margin:auto` will center the block but that naming scheme could cause some accidental changes pretty easily.  Try using `#wrapper`, `#container`, or something of the like.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the naming confusion that might happen with the `<body>`, `<head>`, and `<footer>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong.

`body { ... }` refers to the entire page, the body of your document.

`#body { ... }` is for sure a div in your body with `ID = "body"`. The CSS is correct because it gives a fixed width and automatic margin on the left and on the right.

Answer (score 0):

This will work in modern browsers, but you need to add some more attributes in order to work this in older versions of IE

```
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color:#000;
    background:#fff;
    text-align:center; /* align contents to center which will align #body center */

}
#body {
    width:870px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#ddd;
    text-align:left; /* re-arranges contents of #body to default left */
}
```